# Assigning Disk Partition Space from .CSV file through PowerCLI Script

Tags: powershell, automation, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I am trying to create a PowerCLI script that will create VM's based on settings that are taken from a CSV file. The CSV file is a result of a VBA script extracting data from an Excel spreadsheet that users will have entered their desired settings. What I have so far:

```
$CSVPath = "C:\NewVMList.csv"  

$CSVFILE = Import-CSV $CSVPath  

$VMhost = Get-vmhost "$($CSVFile.VMHost)"  
$PortGroup = Get-VirtualPortgroup -name "$($CSVFile.VLAN)" -VMhost $VMhost  

New-VM -Name "$($CSVFile.Name)" -MemoryGB "$($CSVFile.MemoryGB)" -NumCPU "$($CSVFile.NumCPU)" -portgroup $Portgroup -DiskGB "$($CSVFile.C_System)"
```

The CSV file that it will be referencing for the values will have 3 cells that are available for the various partitions to be assigned space (C:\, D:\, M:(app data)).

What I would like to know is if there is a function that I can use within my PowerCLI script that can assign the various partitions the appropriate amount of space based on the CSV file or if this would need to be done manually?

Would it require something other than the `-DiskGB "$($CSVFile.C_System)"` to create partitions, as this seems to reference the overall disk space being allocated (I am probably wrong, please feel free to correct me)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioning is handled via the Windows OS rather than VMware so you would need to have some sort of post-build task taking over(if you'd like help with that you can create a chat with me, happy to help but theres a bunch of other variables we'd have to discuss)

However the easy and probably better way to accomplish this is to just add 3 separate hard disks to the server.  They are all just VMDK files sitting on a SAN so having 3 disks with 1 partition each is not really much different than having 1 disk with 3 partitions, except you can declare all three disks at VM creation.  so you'd do your `New-VM` with a harddisk size matching the requested size of C:\, then add 2 additional disks using `New-HardDisk`.  This has the added benefit of making it MUCH easier to later extend the C:\ and D:\ drives, and makes your storage more flexible if you ever start having to move VMDK's around for performance or capacity reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I believe I will want to go with your suggestion of having the 3 separate hard disks created for the various drives I need. I am wondering how I could go about specifying the drive letters within my code? The way I have it currently, is this just allocating the total disk space to the new VM and then the guest OS would be assigning it to C:\ by default? This is what somebody on the VM Community website suggested: $eDrive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter “DriveLetter = ‘E:'”
Set-WmiInstance -input $eDrive -Arguments @{DriveLetter=”M:”; Label=”AppData”}

Comment: Drive letters would again have to be done within windows after the server does it's first boot, a bunch of different options there depending how you want to tackle it but easiest is probably to use a customization spec that calls a script to format the drives

Comment: Okay thank you for your help, I really appreciate the insight as I am very new at this. It sounds like I will need to find a way to have my VBA script add a calculation cell that will tally up the total GB required based on the 3 cells representing the drive letters.

Comment: So that code from the VM community would definitely work, but it acts on the server after i'ts booted for the first time, so you'll need to work out a way to actually call it with variables that determine sizes at runtime.  However if you use 3 different drives there's no need to do a calculation for the total size and you can put a runonce script into your sysprepped template that goes ahead and auto-formats each drive with a volume that fills it.  I think most important thing for you right now is going to be seperating out what you need to do from the vm side and what you need to do in OS